# SQL query - order by the first two letters in a column

Tags: sql

I have a SQL query that currently shows these results:

```
Product ID Vendor Site Location 
-----------------------------------------------
ANTIFOAM 51 CHEMICAL COMPANY MANUFACTURING SITE
ANTIFOAM 51 CHEMICAL COMPANY MANUFACTURING SITE
ANTIFOAM 51 CHEMICAL COMPANY HQ HQ-FOOD
ACID 509    CSPA MANUFACTURING SITE
ACID 509    CSPA HQ HQ-FOOD
ACID 509    NORTH MANUFACTURING SITE
ACID 509    NORTH HQ HQ-FOOD
```

I need to order by the HQ first in line then the manufacturing site.

Any help is greatly appreciated !

So it should look like this:

```
Product ID Vendor Site Location
----------------------------------------
ANTIFOAM 51 CHEMICAL COMPANY HQ HQ-FOOD
ANTIFOAM 51 CHEMICAL COMPANY MANUFACTURING SITE
ANTIFOAM 51 CHEMICAL COMPANY MANUFACTURING SITE
ACID 509    CSPA HQ HQ-FOOD
ACID 509    CSPA MANUFACTURING SITE
ACID 509    NORTH HQ HQ-FOOD
ACID 509    NORTH MANUFACTURING SITE
```

Comment: What dbms are you using?

Answer (score 2):

"HQ" comes before "MA" in the en-us locale, so assuming "HQ-FOOD" and "MANUFACTURING SITE" are the only two values in the column, you could just use the default sort order:

```
select * from table order by ID, SiteLocation, Vendor
```

Comment: This does not give the required output. It orders all `HQ-FOOD` records that have the same `ID` before all non-`HQ-FOOD` records with that `ID`, without regard to vendor.

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL:

```
select * from t1
order by
    id,
    regexp_replace(vendor,'\s+HQ$',''),
    case when site_location='HQ-FOOD' then 1 else 2 end
;
```

[image: output]

See [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) for the documentation on `regexp_replace()`.

---

**Test fixture**

```
drop table if exists t1;
create table t1 (product text, id int, vendor text, site_location text );
insert into t1 (product,id,vendor,site_location) values
    ('ANTIFOAM',51,'CHEMICAL COMPANY','MANUFACTURING SITE'),
    ('ANTIFOAM',51,'CHEMICAL COMPANY','MANUFACTURING SITE'),
    ('ANTIFOAM',51,'CHEMICAL COMPANY HQ','HQ-FOOD'),
    ('ACID',509,'CSPA ','MANUFACTURING SITE'),
    ('ACID',509,'CSPA  HQ','HQ-FOOD'),
    ('ACID',509,'NORTH','MANUFACTURING SITE'),
    ('ACID',509,'NORTH HQ','HQ-FOOD')
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see my code (In SQL Server):

```
create table #t2 (product varchar(100), id int, vendor varchar(100), site_location varchar(100) );
insert into #t2 (product,id,vendor,site_location) values
    ('ANTIFOAM',51,'CHEMICAL COMPANY','MANUFACTURING SITE'),
    ('ANTIFOAM',51,'CHEMICAL COMPANY','MANUFACTURING SITE'),
    ('ANTIFOAM',51,'CHEMICAL COMPANY HQ','HQ-FOOD'),
    ('ACID',509,'CSPA ','MANUFACTURING SITE'),
    ('ACID',509,'CSPA  HQ','HQ-FOOD'),
    ('ACID',509,'NORTH','MANUFACTURING SITE'),
    ('ACID',509,'NORTH HQ','HQ-FOOD')

select product,id,vendor,site_location
from #t2
order by vendor desc

drop table #t2
```

Output:

```
ACID    509 NORTH HQ    HQ-FOOD
ACID    509 NORTH   MANUFACTURING SITE
ACID    509 CSPA  HQ    HQ-FOOD
ACID    509 CSPA    MANUFACTURING SITE
ANTIFOAM    51  CHEMICAL COMPANY HQ HQ-FOOD
ANTIFOAM    51  CHEMICAL COMPANY    MANUFACTURING SITE
ANTIFOAM    51  CHEMICAL COMPANY    MANUFACTURING SITE
```